# Scikit classification comparison/ranking

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am new to scikit, and I'm following the example here

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#exercise-3-cli-text-classification-utility

However, I was wondering if, the strings that I wanted to classify, A and B, were both classified under the same document group from the Naiive Bayes, would I be able to find out which string was more likely to be classify under the document group?

For example, if the document group was 'computer graphics' and I had a string "Computers are cool", and another string "OpenGL and CUDA are cool", while they both might be classified under that document group, the second string might be more strongly classified under that one because it's tf-idf score might be higher. Is there a way for me to find that out after I have classified them, so that I could find out which string is the stronger representative of the category?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the classifiers in scikit have a method `predict_proba` which returns the predicted probability that the given test data falls into any of the available output categories.  ([Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.predict_proba) is the one for Gaussian Naive Bayes, for instance.)  You can use this to figure out how confident the model is about the classification.